# Logging for different data types in C

Tags: c, pointers, void

I'm writing some `C` code for a data logging type function.  Get value from variable, perform simple operation, and shove data into another variable.

The key here, is accommodating so many different data types and operations on the data.  I tried using void pointers to all the different variables.  I then call the same function for each.

Take a glance at the function.  You’ll see I’m rewriting the code over and over for each different data type.

```
    /***********************************************************/
    static void GenData(USHORT data_type,
                         USHORT operation,
                         void *var_p,
                         void *data_p)
    /***********************************************************/
   {
      switch (data_type)
      {
      case (DATA_INT):
        switch (operation) {
        case (OP_ONE_SHOT):
          *(int*)data_p = *(int*)var_p;
          break;
        case (OP_COUNTER):
          *(int*)data_p += 1;
          break;
        case (OP_CURR_TIME):
          *(int*)data_p = (int)sytime;
        case (OP_ELAPSED_TIME):
          *(int*)data_p += delta_tick_time;
          break;
        case (OP_MIN):
          if (*(int*)data_p > *(int*)var_p) {
            *(int*)data_p = *(int*)var_p;
          }
          break;
        case (OP_MAX):
          if (*(int*)data_p < *(int*)var_p) {
            *(int*)data_p = *(int*)var_p;
          }
          break;
        case (OP_ADD_ITSELF):
          *(int*)data_p += *(int*)data_p;
          break;
        default:
          break;
        }
        break;

      case (DATA_BYTE):
        switch (operation) {
        case (OP_ONE_SHOT):
          *(BYTE*)data_p = *(BYTE*)var_p;
          break;
        case (OP_COUNTER):
          *(BYTE*)data_p += 1;
          break;
        ...
        ...

      case (DATA_SHORT):
        ...and so on...
    }
```

Arithmetic on a void pointer in `C` isn't valid.  I'm not sure that means that I can't make this function better.  Is there a way I can write this so I don't have to rewrite the "mathy" parts over and over?

As always, thank you for your time and efforts to help.

Comment: Please post the exact error message, copy and paste your compiler error.

Comment: Possibly related: [Is there a generic conversion specifier for printf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26728333/is-there-a-generic-conversion-specifier-for-printf/26728390#26728390)

Comment: You could use templates for the types which end up having the same code, but in the end, the reason the types are different is that they are different and your code will be different.     Are you planning to allow ++ on double?   Are you going to have a type for ratios, won't its code be different? 

Depending on which compiler you are using you might be able to use "typeof" to pass in a type to cast things to.  

If cases can be combined you can also combine them in your switch statements.   However, you need the types so that the overflows/underflow operations occur in the correct place.

Comment: I think this code here is rather a symptom of a problem than the problem itself. You should probably revise the architecture of the software this component is in: why it does need a bunch of different types this way? There may be reasons, though. If so, a good approach may be Dmitry Grigoryev's answer. You may also want to revise what those pointer parameters are for: are they really C data types, or storage formats? If the latter, this approach may be wrong, for example for the matter of endianess.

Comment: @Jubatian I'm passing values in variables to a module which sends it to a database.  I have to hold the values for about 1-60 seconds, and do this operation on it (once or many times over).

Comment: @user432209: That's "downstream", I guess with similarly "hairy" stuff, since you simply have to do it that way once it happened somewhere up. What is above, that is, what needs to use (call) a routine of this kind? It would seem very strange for me to have something alike coming from an "external" source, like a requirement along the lines "I need to perform XY operations on ZQ C language types" (especially the "C language types" part, at some point I would rather expect those to be data formats, that is, language independent specification).

Answer (score 2):

It's relatively easy to create boilerplate code using macros...

```
#define CASE(DATA_TYPE, TYPE) \
  case (DATA_TYPE): \
    switch (operation) { \
    case (OP_ONE_SHOT): \
      *(TYPE*)data_p = *(TYPE*)var_p; \
      break; \
    case (OP_COUNTER): \
      *(TYPE*)data_p += 1; \
      break; \
    case (OP_CURR_TIME): \
      *(TYPE*)data_p = (int)sytime; \
    ...etc...

static void GenData(USHORT data_type,
                     USHORT operation,
                     void *var_p,
                     void *data_p)
{
  switch (data_type)
  {
    CASE(DATA_INT, int)
    CASE(DATA_BYTE, BYTE)
    CASE(DATA_SHORT, short)
    ...etc...
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't seem to get this to compile due to the use of `data_p` and `var_p` inside the macro.  `error C2100: illegal indirection`

Comment: @user432209 I can't guess what's wrong without seeing your exact code.  [Here's a self-contained example program](http://ideone.com/75VVpd) that compiles cleanly....

Comment: @Tony D That helped me fix it.  Got the syntax right, now to debug.

Comment: @AlterMann: sorry about that - I only saw the first version of your post before posting and it seemed significantly different, though we were both looking to use macros to simplify the code.  I see your later edits made our answers similar indeed (and you'd bothered to line up your backslashes! - I was too lazy).  Cheers.

Comment: @TonyD,  yes,  it was hard to line up the backslashes :)

Answer (score 2):

Another solution would be to cast both arguments to a single type which supports all the required operations and accomodates the longest type you support (say, long int). Then you could perform the operation and cast the result back to the type you need:

```
static long DoOperation(USHORT operation, long var, long data)
{
    switch(operation) {
        case(OP_ONE_SHOT):
            return data;
        case (OP_COUNTER):
            return data+1;
        [...etc...]
    }
}
static void GenData(USHORT data_type,
                     USHORT operation,
                     void *var_p,
                     void *data_p)
{
    switch(data_type) {
        case (DATA_INT):
            *(int*)data_p = (int)DoOperation(operation, *(int*)var_p, *(int*)data_p);
            break;
        case (DATA_BYTE):
            *(BYTE*)data_p = (BYTE)DoOperation(operation, *(BYTE*)var_p, *(BYTE*)data_p);
            break;
        [...etc...]
    }

}
```

Of course, there is no guarantee that such type exists.

Comment: Gets my upvote for a worthwhile suggestion, though there are edge cases that get more complicated, e.g. each of `double` and `int64_t` can represent values that the other can't.

Comment: Well, the idea I had is to avoid instantiating the same code multiple times. Since arithmetic for float/double is completely different from integer arithmetic, it cannot be handled by this approach. `int64_t` can be handled correctly if you modify `DoOperation` to work with `int64_t` type.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem are that the Arithmetic operation are invalid you can use some local variable, of the correct type, casting the pointer to assign the value at the local variable, then execute the operation on the local variable and finally copy the new value back to the pointer...

```
/***********************************************************/
static void GenData(USHORT data_type,
                     USHORT operation,
                     void *var_p,
                     void *data_p)
/***********************************************************/
{
  int int_data, int_var;      

  switch (data_type)
  {
  case (DATA_INT):
    switch (operation) {
    case (OP_ONE_SHOT):
      *(int*)data_p = *(int*)var_p;
      break;
    case (OP_COUNTER):
      //*(int*)data_p += 1;
      int_data = *(int*)data_p;
      int_data +=1;
      *(int*)data_p= int_data;
      break;
    case (OP_CURR_TIME):
      *(int*)data_p = (int)sytime;
    case (OP_ELAPSED_TIME):
      //*(int*)data_p += delta_tick_time;
      int_data = *(int*)data_p;
      int_data += delta_tick_time;
      *(int*)data_p= int_data;
      break;
      //...and so on...
```

Comment: In your code, `*(int*)data_p= int_data;` and similar lines overwrite an `int`'s worth of data at the caller-specified memory address, even though the data at that address might be of a different size (e.g. only a `BYTE`).  That causes undefined behaviour.

Comment: I have show only the case of `int` type, if the type is a `char` or a `long`, you must use a local variable of the correct type.
When call the function you must set `data_type` to the correct value for the passed type.
The only way for ensure that the data are of the correct type is write a function for data type, and don't use a void pointer.